# Php - Prevent a User from Accessing a Page when He/She Typed the URL

Tags: php

I have a simple web application with add, edit delete and select functions. There is also a login page to identify whether a user is logged in whenever he/she tried to access a page.

When the user typed in a URL that doesn't require authentication such as the link

/controller/login_read/

how can you prevent he/she from accessing that page ? In this scenario, one cannot simply use session variables and check if user is logged in because the function called by the controller happens before the user is logged in and it doesn't really require checking if the user details are set.

Comment: I believe you are using some kind of a framework with routing. If so, you need to provide details of your framework to get help. If there was no framework, the url /controller/login_read/ would fire the file /controller/login_read/index.php (.html, ...) before anything else, at which point you could check for the login.

Comment: Another thing is that even if the user is logged in, he/she still can't access that page because it was meant to be hidden. Are there any ways to prevent anyone from accessing it through direct URL typing ?
basically, the function is fired when the link /controller/doSomething/login_read is called. Login read will check if the user has an existing account. What I can't seem to figure out is to how to keep this page secret or at least display you are not authorized to access this page from anyone. The controller in this case doesn't have an index. It only has functions for login and logout.

Comment: You could do this at server level with `.htaccess`. Could password protect the directory.

Comment: @Anon PHP does not run anything in `controller` when you open the `/controller/doSomething/login_read` url. You must have some kind of re-routing, most probably a framework. Unless you tell us what it is, we can't help you.

Comment: @codeth Absolutely. However, I would refrain from advising to change .htaccess, especially to someone without proper experience with it. It could mess things up pretty quickly and leave the dev clueless how to fix it.